# Why is nofail ignored for bind mounts in /etc/fstab?

Tags: fstab, bind-mount

I have added the following line to `/etc/fstab` (don't ask for a reason,
it is a completely separate discussion that does not affect this question):

```
/nonexistent /bin none ro,bind,nofail 0 0
```

On boot I get a bunch of systemd errors. They scroll past way too fast for me to tell for sure, but I think I see at least one at the top about failing to mount something and then a bunch of unrelated but presumably dependent failures. The dependency problem is severe as I end up without even a tty. `journalctl` after `chroot`ing presents no relevant info. If there is another way to inspect what exactly is failing, please comment below, and I will add the info to the post.

In any case, this is puzzling to me as I expected `nofail` to just skip in case of nonexistent directories. In fact removing `bind` does just that. Why is the behavior different for `bind`? Is there another option I am not aware of that would skip on error?

Comment: use your phone camera to record a video of the boot messages  ... you may be able to read the systemd message that way

Comment: The thing is that the screen flickers at boot and I think this causes some messages to not be displayed at all. Anyway I'll try it tomorrow at work and edit my post if anything useful comes up.